# Transition property not working when conditionally rendering element

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

```js
function App() {
  const [error, setError] = useState({isError: false, message: ''});

  function checkFiles(e: React.DragEvent<HTMLDivElement>){
    const fileList = e.dataTransfer.files;

    if (fileList.length > 1){
      setError({isError: true, message: 'Bad'}); 
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      {
        error.isError && <Alert severity="error" className={`fixed w-screen -top-12 transition-all duration-500 ${error.isError && 'translate-y-12'}`}>{error.message}</Alert>
      }
    </>
  )
}
```

I'm trying to animate an error notification to go down from above the UI. The `translate-y-12` class is being applied but my transition isn't working.

I have tried changing `transition-all` to `transition-transform`.

I believe it is something similar to:

[React onMount animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68893492/react-onmount-animations)

[React - animate mount and unmount of a single component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40064249/react-animate-mount-and-unmount-of-a-single-component)

Comment: Just accept your answer (click the grey checkmark) but don't say in the question that it's solved.

Comment: I have to wait 2 days before I can mark it as a answer

Answer (score 0):

Got `translate-y-12` property to work by not conditionally rendering the component.